# How to avoid program termination for urllib2.httperror 404 error and display appropriate message

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping the content out of 100k systematic URLS (example.com/entry/1 > example.com/entry/100000).

However, around 10% of the URLs have been deleted, meaning when the script gets to them it gives me the error "urllib2.httperror http error 404" and stops running.

I'm relatively new to python and was wondering if there's a way to do something like this:

```html
if result == error:
    div_text = "missing"
```

So that the loop can continue to the next URL, but make a note that it failed.

Answer (score 1):

`urllib2.HTTPError` is an exception raised by Python. You can wrap your URL call with a try/except block:

```
try:
    # ... put your URL open call here ... 
except urllib2.HTTPError:
    div_text = 'missing'
```

This way, if this exception is encountered again, the Python interpreter will run the code inside that except block.